# How to create relation between one entity and others entities types using child id and child type in C# .net core EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I want to create a direct relation between the Task entity and the child entities, to get with the task the corresponding child and when I get the child to get the corresponding task.

I have an entity named Task and I need to relate it with other entities types one2one. My solution was to create in the task entity one propriety for the child id and one for the child type:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1{ get; set; }
    public Child2 Child2{ get; set; }
} 

public class Child1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task{get; set;}
}    

public class Child2
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for inheritance and a discriminator column? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration

Comment: Something like this, but I don't know how to create the relation in model builder for every child type

Answer (score 0):

The properties of `Child1` and `Child2` classes are the same, why did you create 2 separate classes? Wouldn't it work to do it this way with a single class?

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child1> Childs{ get; set; }
} 

public class Child1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int TaskId { get; set; }
   public Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: there are not the same, it's a simplified example. The  child1 and child2 are 2 differed objects

Answer (score 0):

You configure your relationships by convention:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx

Therefore the naming is important Change the foreign Keys in the Task Model:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    
    public int Child1Id { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1{ get; set; }
    
    public int Child2Id { get; set; }
    public Child2 Child2{ get; set; }
}
```

Alternative solution, relationship by Fluent API configuration:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx
With IEntityTypeConfiguration.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1{ get; set; }
    public Child2 Child2{ get; set; }
} 

public class Child1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task{get; set;}
}    

public class Child2
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task {get; set;}
}
```

The implementtion of IEntityTypeConfiguration:

```
    internal class Child1DbConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Child1>
    {

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child1> entity)
    {
                entity.ToTable("Child1");
                entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
    
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Task)
                    .WithOne(p => p.Child1)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to make a new migration after adding/editing the IEntityTypeConfiguration interface.

Also: Maybe choose another name for your Task class. Task is already a Class name in the 'System.Threading' namespace. So if you use anything async, you will run in to trouble sooner or later.

Thanks for CodeCaster for correcting my (wrong) Answer!

Comment: No, you don't have to do this, it all works by convention.

Comment: I have 8 child types and I don't want to create a new childId prop for every child entity. The relation is one2one, I tried you version but the problem is I have the same childId for different entities the unique combination is ChildId, TaskTypeId

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue before, so since this is one to one table I suggest you used [Own] entity, which will map everything in the same table as the parent and remove headache.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1{ get; set; }
    public Child2 Child2{ get; set; }
} 

[Owned]
public class Child1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task{get; set;}
}    

[Owned]
public class Child2
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Task Task {get; set;}
}
```

Else, if you prefer them to be in separate table and you want to query them from the child, you can also make the `Child.Id` as the PK and FK at the same time, and referencing to `Task` table.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Child1)
        .WithOne(e => e.Task)
        .HasForeignKey<Child1>(e => e.Id)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Child2)
        .WithOne(e => e.Task)
        .HasForeignKey<Child2>(e => e.Id)
        .IsRequired();
}
```